# AD domain name migration to a new AD domain

Tags: windows, active-directory

Just want to ask if there is a best way in migrating Active Directory Domain name. Also what is the best first to migrate is it users, workstations, groups or servers?

Really need your help guys.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello Lawrence and welcome. This question may possible duplicate with https://serverfault.com/questions/122250/migrate-active-directory-to-new-server. or https://serverfault.com/questions/274548/possible-way-to-migrate-a-small-active-directory-domain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate Active Directory to new server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122250/migrate-active-directory-to-new-server)

Comment: You need to add more detail on exactly what you are doing, migrating to a new forest or simply a new server

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to migrate your Active Directory to a new server, or to rename your domain.

In case of migration to new server, just install new server and join it to the domain. Install the Active Dictory role and other components and you domain will be migrated. You will find more info here: [Migrate Active Directory to new server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122250/migrate-active-directory-to-new-server)

If you want to rename you domain, you will find more information here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1347.renaming-a-windows-server-2008-active-directory-domain-dsforum2wiki.aspx

Steps may vary depending on your Windows Server version and also software used in your domain (eg. when you have Exchange server setup).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you just join a new server and promote it to a domain controller. you can always just clean your existing domain controller.